# jQuery slideToggle Multiple Divs At One Time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code,

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$('.showhide').click(function(e) {
$(this).nextAll('.dropdown:lt(1)').slideToggle(100);
e.stopPropagation();
});
$(window).click(function(e) {
var container = $(".dropdown");
if (container.is(':visible') && !$(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length) {
container.hide();
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="showhide">Button</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<a href="#">Update</a>
<a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>


<a class="showhide">Button</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<a href="#">Update</a>
<a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
```

This code is Opening & Closing the divs fine. Also, if I click outside while div is open it's closing them fine.

But, problem is that it's opening multiple divs at one time if I click them one after other. How can I open only one div at one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {


$('.showhide').click(function(e) {
el = $(this).nextAll('.dropdown:lt(1)')
el.slideToggle(100);
$('.dropdown').not(el).hide();//hide all execpt the current one
e.stopPropagation();
});
$(window).click(function(e) {
var container = $(".dropdown");
if (container.is(':visible') && !$(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length) {
container.hide();
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="showhide">Button</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<a href="#">Update</a>
<a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>


<a class="showhide">Button</a>
<div class="dropdown" style="display:none">
<a href="#">Update</a>
<a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide `siblings` when you click on any `showhide` element.

```js
$('.dropdown').hide()

$('.showhide').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).siblings('.showhide').next('.dropdown').slideUp()
  $(this).next('.dropdown').slideToggle(100);
});

$(window).click(function(e) {
  var container = $(".dropdown");
  if (container.is(':visible') && !$(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length) {
    container.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
a.showhide {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="showhide">Button</a>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Update</a>
  <a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>


<a class="showhide">Button</a>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Update</a>
  <a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
```